# How to query input UTXOs of a transaction

Tags: cardano-db-sync

Could anyone help to query input UTXOs of a transaction, please?

I tried to use tx_in and tx_out tables to view the detail inputs and outputs of the transaction https://cardanoscan.io/transaction/81a53921f59028c56eb7920d944d1db5997f27fbae249fa520413990c4a7d944?tab=utxo

First of all, I could get the outputs of the transaction easily by using the following query

[image]

[image]

However, when trying to get Input UTXOs using SQL queries, there was an issue I would like to describe as the following.

1. I've tried to query data from tx_in table to get tx_in_id that is used for the transaction

```
select * from tx_in where tx_out_id = 76360126; -> There are 2 tx_id 76360263 and 76363286
```

[image]
2. Then I tried to query back to the table tx_out with 2 above tx_id. However, it shows more addresses than those on Cardanoscan; some are not actually used in the transaction. How Could I get the exact Input UTXOs of a transaction?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for this:
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/blob/master/doc/interesting-queries.md#transaction-inputs-for-specified-transaction-hash

Comment: Yeah, Thank you. The query works fine.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it.